# What's the name for $r=\cos^3\theta$ (alternatively $x^2+y^2=x^{3/2}$)?

Tags: terminology, polar-coordinates, curves

The curve appeared while solving [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3722496).
I tried to look up both $r=\cos^3\theta$ and $x^2+y^2=x^{3/2}$,
and even clicked almost all the links [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/PolarCurves.html) on wolfram.com .
[image]
This image is for $r=4\cos^3\theta$.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its in the wolfram source you cite above - its a folium https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Folium.html

Comment: Yeah I see now, thanks, the case $\frac{b}{a}=4$

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a folium. See example picture below (from Google images).

[image]

Comment: Aaah this thing I didn't try -- searching by an image. Thanks. You're right.